# How to add a plus character at the left side of the div

Tags: html, css

I'm having some div and trying to add a plus character at the left side of the div after a `h3` element. I've managed to add the plus with `span` but it won't go to the left side, it stays centered..

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.chatter
{
   margin-top:5px;
   width:70%;
   border-spacing:5px;
   table-layout: fixed;
   empty-cells:show;
   border-collapse:separate;
   font:78%/130% "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
   border:1px solid gray;
   box-shadow:0px -1px 2px 1px #d2d6d8;
    border-top:1px solid #eee;
    border-right:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    border-left:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d2d5d7;
   border-radius:3px;
   font-size:large;
}
.c_head
{
    box-shadow:0px -1px 2px 1px #d2d6d8;
    border-top:1px solid #eee;
    border-right:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    border-left:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    padding-right:9px;
    height:31px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    border-radius:3px;
}
.c_header
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:9px;
    color:#777777;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:31px;
    line-height:31px;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="height:100%; background-color:Silver;">
    <center>
        <div class="chatter" runat="server">
            <div class="c_head">
                <h3 class="c_header">Chat - BETA<span style="text-align:left; padding-left:0; position:relative; left:0;">+</span></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

How can I possibly set it so it aligns to the left in the `div`? I've tried anything by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that by positioning the `<span>` element `absolute`ly and give a `position` of `relative` to the `<div>` to establish a containing block for the absolutely positioned element.

Then you could play with `left` or other offsets to move the element to the right position.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.chatter {
  margin-top:5px;
  width:70%;
  border-spacing:5px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  empty-cells:show;
  border-collapse:separate;
  font:78%/130% "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  border:1px solid gray;
  box-shadow:0px -1px 2px 1px #d2d6d8;
  border-top:1px solid #eee;
  border-right:1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-left:1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-bottom:1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-radius:3px;
  font-size:large;

  margin-left: auto;  /* <-- Added declarations  */
  margin-right: auto; /*     instead of <center> */
  text-align: center; /*     dropped element.    */
}
.c_head {
  box-shadow:0px -1px 2px 1px #d2d6d8;
  border-top:1px solid #eee;
  border-right:1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-left:1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-bottom:1px solid #d2d5d7;
  padding-right:9px;
  height:31px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:1px;
  border-radius:3px;
  position: relative; /* <-- Added declaration */
}
.c_header {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  padding-left:9px;
  color:#777777;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:31px;
  line-height:31px;
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-bottom:3px;
}

.c_header > span {
  position:absolute;  /* <-- Edited declaration */
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="height:100%; background-color:Silver;">
  <div class="chatter" runat="server">
    <div class="c_head">
      <h3 class="c_header">Chat - BETA<span>+</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As a side-note: `<center>` element has been deprecated since HTML 4 and removed since HTML 5 — But some web browsers still support it. Therefore it shouldn't be used for new projects.

Instead, in order to align block-level elements at the center you could set the left and right `margin` of the element to`auto`. And for inline-level elements, you could set `text-align: center` on the parent element.

Comment: Seems like I didn't think about it. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just float it left? You might also then want to clear the float on the enclosing container.

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
...
<div class="c_head group">
  <h3 class="c_header">Chat - BETA<span style="float:left; padding-left:0; position:relative; left:0;">+</span></h3>
</div>
```

Depends on which browsers you are supporting.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper" style="height:100%; background-color:Silver;">
    <center>
        <div class="chatter" runat="server">
            <div class="c_head">
                <div class="plus"> <h3> +     </h3> </div>
                <div class="c_header"> <h3>Chat - BETA</h3> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.chatter
{
   margin-top:5px;
   width:70%;
   border-spacing:5px;
   table-layout: fixed;
   empty-cells:show;
   border-collapse:separate;
   font:78%/130% "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
   border:1px solid gray;
   box-shadow:0px -1px 2px 1px #d2d6d8;
    border-top:1px solid #eee;
    border-right:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    border-left:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d2d5d7;
   border-radius:3px;
   font-size:large;
}
.c_head
{
    box-shadow:0px -1px 2px 1px #d2d6d8;
    border-top:1px solid #eee;
    border-right:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    border-left:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d2d5d7;
    border-radius:3px;
}
.c_header
{
    width:70%;
    color:#777777;
    height:100%;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.plus {width:30%; height:100%; float:left; font-size:31px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ockzukjs/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline styles to the h3 in the HTML

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.chatter {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 70%;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  empty-cells: show;
  border-collapse: separate;
  font: 78%/130%"Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px 1px #d2d6d8;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: large;
}
.c_head {
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px 1px #d2d6d8;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d5d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d5d7;
  padding-right: 9px;
  height: 31px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.c_header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 9px;
  color: #777777;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  position: relative;
}
.c_header:before {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.c_header:after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="height:100%; background-color:Silver;">
  <center>
    <div class="chatter" runat="server">
      <div class="c_head">
        <h3 class="c_header">Chat - BETA</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

**What I did:**

Changed this line of HTML

```
<h3 class="c_header">Chat - BETA</h3>
```

add this to CSS

```
    .c_header
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        padding-left:9px;
        color:#777777;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:31px;
        line-height:31px;
        font-size:1.2em;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding-bottom:3px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .c_header:before {
      content:"+";
      position: absolute;
      left:0;
    }
    .c_header:after {
      content:"+";
      position: absolute;
      right:0;
    }
```